# Calculating height of an object in an image giving more error percentage than calculating width

Tags: swift, image, math, camera

My application’s requirement is to measures object of interest’s height and width from the captured image.

I am thinking of implementing formulae behind [scantips](https://www.scantips.com/lights/subjectdistance.html) website.

I was checking the accuracy of [scantips](https://www.scantips.com/lights/subjectdistance.html) and found that width measurement is more accurate than height.

I entered iPhone 7’s focal length 3.99 and crop ratio as 28/3.99 = 7.0175438596. 28 is focalLenIn35mmFilm. I got this info from captured image’s EXIF data.
I entered the image height, height of object in image and manually calculated distance from that object.

Observation: Height is giving more error percentage than width. Width’s error percentage is around 2-4% but height’s is more than 10%.

Any pointers in the right direction will helps a lot.

Comment: Show the captured image itself and give actual / measured dimensions.